# CSS ignore child element's dimensions when calculating parent element height

Tags: html, css

I have a container element that is automatically resizing according to its children, while maintaining its assigned padding and margin values.
If i adjust the dimensions of a child element then the parent resizes.
I wish to exclude a specific child element from this resizing process.

The following snippet illustrates the problem:

```
<div id="div1">
  <button id="button1">Dummy</button>
  <span>My parent div has increased in height</span>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#div1 {
background-color: red;
  padding: 15px;

}
#button1 {
  vertical-align: super;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Here is also a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c9THxzhHd5HYt2spmTlI?p=preview).

I wish the height of `#div1` to be unaffected by the position of `#button1`.